# Display coordinates from 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates

```
let World = {
    x: Player.playerX,
    y: Player.playerY,
    width: 5,
    height: 5,
    newX: 0,
    map: [
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0],
         [0,0,0]]
         ,

    createMap: function(){
        for(let row = 0; row < this.map.length; row++){
            for(let column = 0; column < this.map.length; column++){
              //Display information to console.log
              console.log(this.map[row][column]) ???
              console.log(this.map[row][0]); ???
              console.log(row[0][0]) ???
              console.log(column[0][1]) ???

        }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to write to the specific coordinates to the console but nothing is working after trying for so long.

So I can check if a player is at a specific coordinate to do something.

For example.

```
if (player.X == row[2] and player.Y == column[1]){
  do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over `row` length to get the `column` values for that specific row.

```
createMap: function(){
        for(let row = 0; row < this.map.length; row++){
            for(let column = 0; column < this.map[row].length; column++){
              console.log(this.map[row][column]);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I had my code like that at one point, but my problem is how would I display and || check which coordinate the player is on based on what I wrote in my example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  don't you already know the player coordinates through Player.X and Player.Y?

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to detect when someone is on a certain coordinate. If, so then do something

Comment: Then why not just test `this.map[Player.Y][Player.X] == somevalue`?

Comment: I've figured it out yesterday myself but I still appreciate the help. I forgot to give you Correct answer. Thank you